# How to assign a list into an another list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
num = 8
order = []
p = 0

for i in range(num):
    for t in range(i+1 , num):
        order[p] = [i,t]
        p += 1
```

I want to set some data like [0,0] , [0,1] ... [2,6] , [2,7] , [3,4] , [3,5] , [3,6] , [3,7] , [4,5] ... [6,7] into a list, gives this error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Use list comprehension `[[i,j] for i in range(7) for j in range(7)]`

Comment: It looks like you would want the final element of  the list to be `[7, 7]` and not `[6, 6]`? Moreover, it is not even clear if you want pairs of the same number: `[0, 0]` appears but `[3, 3]` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `append()` method to add item

```
order.append([i,t])
```

Or use a list comprehension

```
print [[i,t] for i in range(num) for t in range(i+1 , num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a list item with order[p] because p in this case is a list index.  What you might want is a dict, if you want to be able to reference them by the p.
Otherwise, use append.

Dict method:

```
num = 8
order = {}
p = 0

for i in range(num):
    for t in range(i+1 , num):
        order[p] = [i,t]
        p += 1

>>> order
{0: [0, 1], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 3], 3: [0, 4], 4: [0, 5], 5: [0, 6], 6: [0, 7], 7: [1, 2], 8: [1, 3], 9: [1, 4], 10: [1, 5], 11: [1, 6], 12: [1, 7], 13: [2, 3], 14: [2, 4], 15: [2, 5], 16: [2, 6], 17: [2, 7], 18: [3, 4], 19: [3, 5], 20: [3, 6], 21: [3, 7], 22: [4, 5], 23: [4, 6], 24: [4, 7], 25: [5, 6], 26: [5, 7], 27: [6, 7]}
>>> order[4]
[0, 5]
```

List append method:

```
num = 8
order = []
p = 0

for i in range(num):
    for t in range(i+1 , num):
        order.append([i,t])
        p += 1

>>> order
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7], [4, 5], [4, 6], [4, 7], [5, 6], [5, 7], [6, 7]]
>>> order[4]
[0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Python list comprehensions. What you want could be achieved by

```
num = 8
order = [[i, t] for t in range(i+1, num) for i in range(num)]
```

The error you get is because you initialize an empty list (`order=[]`) and then try to access elements of that list `order[p] = [i,t]`. If you want to build up a list step by step, use the `append` method of Python lists.